# Why does my cookie script not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I cant find out what is wrong with my cookie script on this site:
    http://lampen.identitest.dk/

If you go to my site, you will find a hidden

`<div id="popupDiv">`

it does not show because of display: none in css but it should be showing and then if you click on a button it should be hiding in 24 hours.

this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#popupDiv').show();
  }

  // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
  // not show it again until one day has passed.
  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#popupDiv').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
  });

});

// ---
// And some generic cookie logic
// ---
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

I have found the cookie script on

```
http://jsfiddle.net/FcFW2/1/
```

and this is tested and works in a default html document with jQuery on.

I hope someone can help me out :)

Best regards Shane

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? what is the issue?

Comment: Please include relevant code within your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that I have tried different solutions on my site but i have updated the question now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your script tag declaration.

It should be `<script type="text/javascript">`

Currently it's `<script type="type/javascript">`

I don't see any errors in your code.

Comment: that solved it ! I been looking at the code for hours and does not have much hair left so thank you. What an embarrassing error.

Comment: @ShaneAkira Glad to hear that. You can use `console.log()` to debug the code.